# Function in promise returns undefined

Tags: node.js, function, promise

I am trying to make a promise in nodejs, that will call a function from an external file. The function makes a POST call (this is in an external file because it will be used by other codes as well), and I am trying to catch a specific header in the response.
I am able to make the call when I make a promise in the function itself, but I think the correct way to write this code is to have the function separate and the promise in the main code's body.
I have this server.js:

```
import { getOkapiToken } from './functions.js'
import settings from './jsons/config.json';
let OkapiKey = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  //Call function to make API post call  
  let keytoken = getOkapiToken(settings.url,settings.userauth,settings.passauth)
  if (keytoken.length == 201) {
    resolve(keytoken)
  } else {
    reject(`There was an error: ${keytoken}`)
  }
})

OkapiKey.then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error('I have an error:'+err.code);
})
```

And this functions.js file:

```
import post from 'axios';

export function getOkapiToken(url, user, password) {
//Get username and password for API
const auth = {
  "username": user,
  "password": password
};

//Create headers for POST request
const options = {
  method: 'post',
  data: auth,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': auth.length,
    'X-Okapi-Tenant': 'diku'
  }
};
  //Make API post call
post(url, options)
    .then(response => {
      return(response.headers['x-okapi-token'])
    }).catch((err) => {
        return(`There was an error 2: ${err}`)
})
  }
```

When I run the function in the main file, it works correctly. But when I do it this way, I get the "catch" message: I have an error:undefined.

At first I thought it might be a sync issue, so I added "await" before the new promise:

```
let OkapiKey = await new Promise((resolve,reject)
```

But this returned an error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

Comment: You're trying to wrap async function by `new Promise`. Why? Turn `getOkapiToken` into async function and use it accordingly

Comment: Code has multiple issues. Start by returning Promise from `getOkapiToken()`, ie `return post(url, options).....`